# Can I update my Mutablelist over the internet?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, mutablelist

I am new here. I have an Android app(Kotlin) that displays questions with multiple choice. The user selects an answer and submits. Then the next question is displayed.

I have a mutable list of the answers and questions. Is it possible for me to update the questions and answers over the internet?

I don't want a situation where users will always have to update app to get updated questions

Comment: This is a pretty broad question because there are many ways to do this. But in general you just need to put your questions in a web-accessible endpoint, probably using JSON, and have your app pull the questions from that rather than using hard-coded questions in your Kotlin code.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, your question is too broad so i'll give you how the process should be and topics you can research on your own implement your scenario.

- use Retrofit with Kotlin coroutines to fetch you questions data from a RESTFul API
- store the loaded questions in a Room persistent storage DB
- using LiveData load the question from your DB and display them to user each time they login or use swipe to refresh

This way your application can work offline as well as fetch new questions from server when it's online

How to create / implement a service to generate or load you questions from remote DB is out of scope can be done using NodeJS or Swagger.

Topics you need to research:

[Using Retrofit with Coroutines](https://proandroiddev.com/using-retrofit-2-with-kotlin-coroutines-cb112f0fb738)

[Storing data in local DB Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

[working with live data](https://androidwave.com/working-with-livedata/)

[Monitor connectivity status and connection metering](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-status-type)

**Experiment with this**

If you want to use a generic API that can generate general topic questions:

[Trivia API](https://opentdb.com/api_config.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I will research and give you feedback

Comment: I've done that. Although, I was told I have less than 15 reputation. Thanks

Comment: I hope the links are helping you well, comment here if you need help

Comment: Thank you.
I would like to display a range of int as a list in a textview. see what  i have tried. it only displays the last int: 7
meanwhilem i want [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for(g in 0..7){
            textView.text=g.toString()
        }

Comment: This is a different question you should post separately, but anyway you should use the textview    .append(CharSequence text) method